# Inserting the Sitecore media files as link in the email template of Sitecore forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore forms in `Sitecore 10.2` but I don't see any option for making a downloadable link by attaching the Sitecore media files in the email template attached to submit action.

As an alternative, I have to go to any rich text editor field and there I could see attaching the Sitecore media files option, so attaching the media files in the RTE generates a link of media files with the .ashx extension then I have to copy that link of the attached media, then I use the link option available in the email template, as in the screenshot below to make it downloadable:

[image]

Is there any way in Sitecore to directly attach the media files in the email template?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, OOTB, it is not possible as whatever submit action you are using it is going to store its value in the `Parameters` field of Submit Action Definition item. So, for example, if you are using `send email` as your submit action it stores the value of the complete form value into the `Parameters` field in JSON format as below -

```
{"to":"test@dgfad.com","from":"default@domain.com","subject":"test","body":"<p>This is for testing </p>}
```

even if you want to use any image in the form builder it will not allow you to use it from Sitecore itself but from your local, you can attach a media which will convert into a base64 string and store it as JSON in the `Parameters` field. Although the user interface for email form builder is controlled from below file -

```
/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Layouts/Renderings/RichTextEditor/RichTextEditor.cshtml
```

I think this is going to be very complex but you do something with this file by adding your custom button and writing your custom javascript to get the link values from Sitecore.